# How to convert paragraph library item (ContentEntityBase) to render array for Twig template

Tags: 9, paragraphs

I'm attempting to render an array of [LibraryItem](https://api.druphelp.com/api/paragraphs/modules%21paragraphs_library%21src%21Entity%21LibraryItem.php/class/LibraryItem/8)s in a twig template but I'm having trouble figuring out how to retrieve the render array.

Currently my twig template looks like this

```
{% set paragraphs = node.getParagraphs() %}

{% for paragraph in paragraphs %}
{{ paragraph }}
{% endfor %}
```

But this gives me the error

> Exception: Object of type Drupal\paragraphs_library\Entity\LibraryItem
> cannot be printed

How would I turn the LibraryItem entity into something printable? I'm willing to do this either on the twig side or in a hook but it would be helpful to know how to do both.

Comment: Output the paragraph fields as their default field formatter in the node "Manage Display" settings, then theme the paragraphs normally using their Paragraph twig files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to know both, here is a Twig solution:

```
{{ paragraph|view }}
```

This is using the [view](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/twig_tweak/-/blob/3.x/docs/cheat-sheet.md#view) filter of the module [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak).

In a multilingual site you need to [translate](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/twig_tweak/-/blob/3.x/docs/cheat-sheet.md#entity-translation) the entity:

```
{{ paragraph|translation|view }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this by using the ViewBuilder like so

```
$paragraphsRender = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getViewBuilder('paragraphs_library_item')
  ->viewMultiple($paragraph_ids);
```